# prove a continuous mapping theorem for $g_n(X_n)\stackrel{d}{\to}g(X)$?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that $X_n\stackrel{d}{\to}X$ where $X_n,X$ take value in a metric space $(\mathbb{D},d)$. We know from continuous mapping theorem that if $g:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{E}$ is a fixed continuous function (independent of $n$), where $\mathbb{E}$ is another metric space, then $g(X_n)\stackrel{d}{\to} g(X)$ as $n\to\infty$.

**My question:** Let $\{g_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of continuous functions such that $g_n\to g$ "pointwisely" on $\mathbb{D}$. Can one conclude that 
$$
g_n(X_n)\stackrel{d}{\to}g(X)?
$$
If not, is there a counterexample?

The proof for the classical continuous mapping theorem uses portmanteau theorem (see the proof of Theorem 1.3.6 on p.20 of van der Vaart and Wellner (1996)). For example, one can prove $g(X_n)\stackrel{d}{\to} g(X)$ by showing that for any closed $F\subset\mathbb{D}$,
$$
\limsup P(g_n(X_n)\in F) = \limsup P(X_n\in g_n^{-1}(F)) \stackrel{?}{\leq} P(g(X)\in F).
$$
where "$\stackrel{?}{\leq}$" is the inequality that I do not know how to show (perhaps not true). Another fact that might be useful is $\limsup P(X_n\in g_n^{-1}(F))\leq P(\limsup\{X_n\in g_n^{-1}(F)\})$.

Thank you!

Comment: some perhaps more general sufficient condition for such type of results to hold is found in Problem 3.5 on p.151 of Ethier and Kurtz (1986)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No: consider $g_n$ defined in the following way: $g_n$ is $0$ outside $[0,2/n]$, 
takes the value $1$ at $1/n$ and is interpolated linearly on $[0,1/n]$ and $[1/n,2/n]$. Let $X_n=1/n$. Then $X_n\to 0$, $g_n\to 0$ pointwise but $g_n\left(X_n\right)=1$ for each $n$.

However, if the convergence of $\left(g_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ to $g$ is uniform, then everything goes well, as 
$$g_n\left(X_n\right)=\underbrace{g_n\left(X_n\right)-g_n\left(X\right)}_{\to 0\mbox{ in probability}  }  +\underbrace{g_n\left(X \right).}_{\to g(X)\mbox{ in distribution}  }  $$

Comment: Awesome, thanks!